# Use mapGetter and mapMutations in Vuex with typescript without class-style components sintax

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, store

I made a project with Vue, but start to be a little bit confused without static types.
I added typescript to my project, but I want to keep using the "normal" way to write my code (without classes and decorators).

I have managed all of my store with typescript keep the "normal" way, but with types, now I want to use mapGetters, mapMutations, and mapActions in my components using typescript, but without class-style components.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default Vue.extend({
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('pictures', ['toggleFavorite']),
    anotherMethodExample: (pictureId: number): void {
      this.toggleFavorite(pictureId); // This line returns an error described bellow.
    },
  },
});
```

Error returned:

```
Property 'toggleFavorite' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, unknown, unknown, { index: unknown; isSelected: unknown; getToggleFavorite: any; /* another methods*/; }, Readonly<{ picture: any; }>>'.
```

How can I use mapGetters and mapActions without `@Component` way? I really don't like this "angular" style to write code, I think that it is better to keep the "normal" format to read and keep update reading the official Vue documentation.

Someone can help me?

Thanks for this o/

Comment: Most likely, you have some untyped `computed` properties. Setting correct types for each computed usually fixes this type of error. I have no idea why, though. If you still can't make it work, please create a [mcve] in codesandbox.io and I'll take a look. I don't mean to brag, but I've been using vue + typescript without `@Component` decorators in the last 3 projects and I haven't come across any case I wasn't able to solve *"the typescript way"* (without any `any`). In short, I went from hating typescript to loving it.

Comment: You're write. I wrong some type of data and belived that typescript didnt work! I removed all methods and tried with only one and works. After this I started to back each method by time and fixed. Thanks for this o/

Comment: Most welcome. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

While searching for a solution for this issue, I found this question. I did some experimenting, and think there is a solution.

Your root cause, as I see that you've figured out by the comments, is that you need to annotate the computed properties. But still, there will be no type safety when injecting the mapped methods from the store module.

The trick is to wrap the methods `mapGetters` and `mapActions` so that it is possible to let Typescript infer the types involved. It will give you compile time errors if you provide the wrong key to the mapper, and as a bonus the return types will be correct (no more **any**)

```
// returns a type which skips the first context argument
type OmitActionContext<F> = F extends (
  context: ActionContext<any, any>,
  ...args: infer P
) => infer R
  ? (...args: P) => R
  : never;

// signature of action methods
type ActionMethod = (
  context: ActionContext<any, any>,
  ...args: any[]
) => Promise<any>;

// needs to be called with extra parenthesis to infer map keys correctly
// such as mapActionsNamespaced<TYPE>()(namespace, map)
function mapActionsNamespaced<
  S extends Record<keyof S & string, ActionMethod>
>(): <Map extends (keyof S & string)[]>(
  namespace: string,
  map: Map
) => {
  [K in Map[number]]: OmitActionContext<S[K]>;
} {
  return <Map extends (keyof S & string)[]>(namespace: string, map: Map) =>
    mapActions(namespace, map) as any;
}
```

Using the above wrapper the *payload* and *Promise* return type will be inferred correctly.

As a bonus, if you would accidentally add *s* to `toggleFavorite` you will get an intellisense error below at compile time.

```
...mapActionsNamespaced<PictureModuleActions>()('pictures', ['toggleFavorites'])
```

[See the following gist for a complete solution](https://gist.github.com/joakimriedel/7aab32e9e69361241fc84e34d2eafab7)